# How to use C popen in a pthread

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, fork, popen

First, I've been reading some comments in forums about it's recommended to avoid using `fork` in threads, and `popen` does fork.

Anyway, I'm doing a program with some threads and it'll be very useful for me to using other library functions which execute `popen`.

When I do that, program exits.

Let me put a simple example because the code is large:

```
int main()
{
    pthread_t thread1, thread2;
    int var=1;
    pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, mythread, &var);
    pthread_create(&thread2, NULL, anotherthread, &var);
...
}

void *mythread(void *s)
{
...
    pthread_detach(pthread_self());
...
    printf("this is printed\n");
    char *str = externalFunctWithPopen();
    printf("this is NEVER printed\n");
...
}

char *externalFunctWithPopen()
{
...
    printf("this is also printed\n");
    popf = popen(command, "r"); 
    printf("this is not printed at all\n");
    while (fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), popf) != 0) {
...
}
```

As I told before, **"this is NEVER printed"** is never printed, and furthermore, main exits, including the other thread called **anotherthread**

Any piece of help is welcome.

Comment: I think it caused by the reason that main() end execution before your thread complete all work. Do you wait for thread end in your main? pthread_join for e.g

Comment: I don't want to do a `pthread_join`, but a `pthread_detach(pthread_self())` inside, and a infinity loop in the thread. The program is a daemon with two threads that never end, and should't be joined

Comment: @mulg0r whatever the threads never ends in fact, but as Nick said your _main_ must not finish. WHat are you doing in _main_ ? if nothing you can _join_ (just to block it) or move one of the two threads behavior into the _main_ thread

Comment: That's fine, but @NickS makes a good point.  If you are not satisfied with that explanation then this would be a good time to update your question to present a [mcve] demonstrating the problem.

Answer (score 1):

> *main exits, including the other thread*

To avoid the behaviour that leaving `main()` tears down all other threads of the same process. leave it via a call to `pthread_exit()` instead of doing `exit()` or just `return`.

Comment: it worked. I did your change and something similar to what @NickS @[user:8209813] purposed: Instead pthread_join in main, I go on with a infinity loop in main and two processes with pthread_detach(pthread_self()). Thanks all! Here you have my positive vote

Comment: @mulg0r To close your question you might want to accept a suitable answer.

Comment: I know, @alk, but it's a mixed between what you wrote, what wrote NickS and what I told you that I did, so I cannot consider just one of them as a complete answer. I hope you understand that. At least you have my positive vote ;)